# How to properly pad numbers in Python's struct

Tags: python, struct, byte

I have a tuple like this (note that first element can be of any size (big but not extremely big, ie. 2**12 - 1 is OK), and second will always be in range [0, 255]).

```py
t = [(0, 137), (0, 80), (0, 78), (0, 71), (0, 13), ...]
```

I want to store these numbers as bytes on the file system (for compression). That means I also want to later use these bits to recover the tuple. Also note that it is a requirement that the Big endian is used.

```py
for idx, v in compressed:              
    if v:                              
        f.write(struct.pack(">I", idx))
        f.write(struct.pack(">I", v))
```

However, when I try to get the numbers, like this:

```py
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:          
    data = file.read(4)                     
    nums = []                               
    while data:                             
        num = struct.unpack(">I", data)[0]  
        print(num)                          
        data = file.read(4)                 
        nums.append(num)
```

I am not getting the numbers above (I am for some numbers, but later it gets messed up, probably because of bit padding).

How to stay consistent with bit padding? How can I add something with `struct.pack('>I, ...)` that I can later reliably get?

Update:

For the following tuple
`[(0, 137), (0, 80), (0, 78), (0, 71), (0, 13), (0, 10), (0, 26), (6, 0), (0, 0), (9, 13), (0, 73), (0, 72), (0, 68), (0, 82), (9, 0), (0, 1), (0, 44), (15, 1), (17, 8), (0, 2), (15, 0), (0, 246) ...]`

I get the following numbers using my approach:

`[0, 137, 0, 80, 0, 78, 0, 71, 0, 13, 0, 10, 0, 26, 9, 13, 0, 73, 0, 72, 0, 68, 0, 82, 0, 1, 0, 44, 15, 1, 17, 8, 0, 2, 0, 246 ...]`

See, at the (6,0) it starts to diverge. Until then it's fine. But it corrects itself?? at  9,13 and continues to do well.

Comment: Exactly, I do not know. That is why I tried Big endian. To indicate whether it should proceed or not.

Comment: @finefoot if you want you can take a look at my updated question

Comment: My number will always be in that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. However, you do have the following line in there:

```
if v:
```

`v` will be `False` for some of those tuples where the second element is `0` which won't be written to the file and therefore you won't see them when reading from that file, again.

---

Also, since you're writing your elements in pairs anyways, you could use `>II` as your format:

```py
from struct import pack, unpack, calcsize

original = [(0, 137), (0, 80), (0, 78), (0, 71), (0, 13), (0, 10), (0, 26), (6, 0), (0, 0), (9, 13), (0, 73), (0, 72), (0, 68), (0, 82), (9, 0), (0, 1), (0, 44), (15, 1), (17, 8), (0, 2), (15, 0), (0, 246)]

filename = "test.txt"
fileformat = ">II"

with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
    for element in original:
        fp.write(pack(fileformat, *element))

with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
    elements = iter(lambda: fp.read(calcsize(fileformat)), b"")
    readback = [unpack(fileformat, element) for element in elements]

print(readback == original)
```

Comment: Hah. Good catch! That was rather tough to spot I believe.

Comment: @DragosStrugar Updated a little bit, maybe you'll find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
compressed = [(0, 137), (0, 80), (0, 78), (0, 71), (0, 13), (0, 10), (0, 26), (6, 0), (0, 0), (9, 13), (0, 73), (0, 72), (0, 68), (0, 82), (9, 0), (0, 1), (0, 44), (15, 1), (17, 8), (0, 2), (15, 0), (0, 246)]
```

try this code for wrting data:

```
import struct

with open('file.dat', 'wb') as f:
    for idx, v in compressed:   
        f.write(struct.pack(">I", idx))
        f.write(struct.pack(">I", v))
```

and this code for reading:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(4)                     
    nums = []
    while data:     
        idx = struct.unpack(">I", data)[0]  
        data = f.read(4)      
        v = struct.unpack(">I", data)[0]
        data = f.read(4)      
        nums.append((idx,v))
```

and `nums` contains:

```
[(0, 137), (0, 80), (0, 78), (0, 71), (0, 13), (0, 10), (0, 26), (6, 0), (0, 0), (9, 13), (0, 73), (0, 72), (0, 68), (0, 82), (9, 0), (0, 1), (0, 44), (15, 1), (17, 8), (0, 2), (15, 0), (0, 246)]
```

Which is the same as the input, in fact `nums == compressed` gives `True`.

Comment: Yes. But look after it.

Comment: What do you mean? @DragosStrugar

Comment: In the question: `See, at the (6,0) it starts to diverge. Until then it's fine. But it corrects itself?? at 9,13 and continues to do well.` The question was resolved by @finefoot

Comment: Ok, I hadn't seen the second part of the question you added. I thought you were asking for something else. Now correct me. Thanks!